# How to convert output timezone per query in sequel ruby?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I wanted to be able to set timezone in each query depending on my user's preferred timezone without adding timezone conversion in each raw sql generated by my application.

I was able to query/retrieve the records in 'Asia/Manila' TZ using this config

```
Sequel.extension :named_timezones
Sequel.application_timezone = 'Asia/Manila'
```

Is it possible to set application_timezone per query so that I will pass the current application user's timezone in each request.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to store the user's preferred time zone and just display the information in their time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use Sequel's thread_local_timezones extension: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/thread_local_timezones_rb.html

This is per thread, not per query, but should hopefully still work for your needs.

Comment: btw is it ok to create thread per logged in user performance wise?

Comment: Probably not a good idea.  I think most people would just define a method that yields and has an ensure clause to set the thread local timezone back to nil.  Then you would call that method around whatever code you wanted in the user-specific timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Store everything in UTC and then convert in the UI/presentation layer.

Comment: Yep we are storing everything in UTC and converting in ui is not a problem.
My problem is in our application we let the user to input sql query in the textbox and run it. We dont want to hussle the user in doing date conversion in each they make for example in where clause where they will enter date in no timezone format